# Translate with Angular2

Tags: angular

I want translate a text , I always use `{{ 'Name' | translate }} in my html`
But now I need use translate en my `.ts` but I have a problem.

```
    this.gridOptions = <GridOptions>{};

    this.columnDefs = [
      {
        headerName: {{'Name' | translate }},
        field: 'name'
      }];

Forbbiden bitwise operation (no-bitwise)
Not found the name translate
hope ','.
hope ';'.
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could use [ngx-translate](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core) for this.

```
constructor(private translate: TranslateService) {
  this.translate.setDefaultLang('en');

  // Initially setting the language as the browser's lang
  if (this.translate.getBrowserLang() !== undefined) {
     this.translate.use(this.translate.getBrowserLang());
  } else {
     this.translate.use('en');
  }
}

generateColDef() {

  // 'APP.NAMESTR' is the key to your Names translation which resides in your language json
  this.translate.get('APP.NAMESTR').subscribe(value => {
    this.columnDefs = [{
       headerName: value,
       field: 'name'
     }]; 

  });
}
```

For a more complete example checkout this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/github/SenalKumarage/ngx-translate101)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use Pipe in `.ts` file like this:

```
import {Pipename} from './pipename';

Pipename.prototype.transform(arguments);
```

No need to use `{{}}` in `.ts` file.

Comment: I can do with  translate.get('Name').subscribe(value => { this.Name = value; } )? Y prefer dont use Pipename in .ts